# flutter bloc library percentage progress bar

Tags: flutter, bloc

How can a `bloc` show percentage progress bar

```
//For example, there is a regular bloc 
@override
  Stream<JobState> mapEventToState(JobEvent event) async* {
    if (event is HardJobEvent) {
      yield* _mapHardJobToState();
    }
  }
  
 
  Stream<UpdateState> _mapHardJobToState() async* {
    try {
      //It is necessary to display a progress bar for this method.
      await doSomeHardJob();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
  
  
  doSomeHardJob() async* {
     for( var i = 1 ; i < 1000; i++ ) { 
       //This yield does not work. Doesn't display any errors
       //State not transfer
       yield HardJob(nowCounter: i);
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use cubit instead of bloc. but the technique should be similar.
I have a broadcast stream controller in the payload generating function. In the event dispatcher (this should be your bloc) I listen to it and emit loading states with a double value. the bloc builder in the widgets can react to it. check put my little implementation:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

/// Model
class Data {
  final DateTime date;
  Data(this.date);
}

/// Repo
class DataRepository {
    /// here comes the trick:
    final StreamController<double> progress = StreamController.broadcast(); // make it broadcast to allow multiple subcribtions

Future<List<Data>> generateData() async {
    /// here comes your time taking work
    progress.sink.add(0.0); // set progress to 0

    List<Data> payload =
    []; // this will be the data you want to transport in the loadED event

await Future.forEach(List.generate(10, (i) => i), (int i) async {
  /// here comes the progess; dont send it too late otherwise
  /// the loadED state will be followed by a loadING state and
  ///  you will see a never ending spinner
  progress.sink.add(i / 10);

  /// this would be like eg a http call
  payload.add(Data(DateTime.now()));
  await Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1)); // simulate the time consuming action
});

    return payload;
  }
}

/// State
@immutable
abstract class DataState {}

class DataInitial extends DataState {
  DataInitial();
}

class DataLoading extends DataState {
  /// this state will emit the actual progress value to the spinner
  final double progress;
  DataLoading(this.progress);

  /// boilerplate code to tell state events apart from each other even     though they are of the same type
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
    return other is DataLoading && other.progress == progress;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => progress.hashCode;
}

class DataLoaded extends DataState {
  /// this state will transport the payload data
  final List<Data> data;
  DataLoaded(this.data);

  /// same as aboth
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
    return other is DataLoaded && other.data == data;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => data.hashCode;
}

/// Cubit
class DataCubit extends Cubit<DataState> {
  /// Cubit works like a simple Bloc
  final DataRepository dataRepository;

  /// the repo will do the actual work
  DataCubit({required this.dataRepository}) : super(DataInitial());

  Future<void> generateData() async {
    /// this will bring the progress value to the loading spinner widget.
    /// each time a new progress is made a new DataLoadING state will be emitted
    dataRepository.progress.stream
    .listen((progress) => emit(DataLoading(progress)));

    /// this await is sincere; it will take aaages; really
    final payload = await dataRepository.generateData();

    /// finally the payload will be sent to the widgets
    emit(DataLoaded(payload));
  }
}

late DataRepository dataRepository;

void main() {
  /// init the repo that will do the heavy lifting like eg a db or http     request
  dataRepository = DataRepository();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// makes the cubit (like a baby bloc) available to all child widgets of the app
    return BlocProvider<DataCubit>(
      create: (context) => DataCubit(dataRepository: dataRepository),
      child: const MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Progress Demo',
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Progress Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: BlocBuilder<DataCubit, DataState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is DataLoading) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(
                value: state.progress,
                  );
                } else if (state is DataLoaded) {
              List<Data> longAnticipatedData = state.data;
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: longAnticipatedData.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) => ListTile(
                    title:
                          Text(longAnticipatedData[i].date.toIso8601String()),
                      ));
            } else {
              /// initial state
              return const Center(
                child: Text('press the FAB'),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        /// generate data; will take a good while
        onPressed: () => context.read<DataCubit>().generateData(),
        child: const Icon(Icons.start),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```